# How to merge a sequence into an embed array and ignore elems that have equal value with embed array elems in specific field?

Tags: rethinkdb

I have a doc like this:

```
{
   "shareRecords": [
                    {"sharer_Id": "user001","update_Id": "update002"}
                    {"sharer_Id": "user001","update_Id": "update003"}
                   ]
   "id": "0"
}
```

and want to merge a sequence to embed array "ShareRecords" by rule:if elem with same "update_Id"'s value existed,ignore it,for example,if I try to merge this sequence:

```
   [
      {"sharer_Id": "user001","update_Id": "update002"}
      {"sharer_Id": "user001","update_Id": "update004"}
   ]
```

the first elem should be ignored due to the elem with same "update_Id" value:"update002" already existed.

### Update

I tried this,but it seems equal to append,no any filtering has been performed,all new records are appended to "shareRecords" directly,what is the mistake here?

```
r.table("table").get("0").update(function(doc) {
  return doc.merge({shareRecords: doc("shareRecords").add(
     r.expr([{"update_Id":"update002"},{"update_Id":"update004"}]).filter(
        function(newRecord) {
           return doc("shareRecords").contains(function(record) {
             return record("update_Id").ne(newRecord("update_Id"))
        })
     })
   )}
)})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right code should be:

```
r.table("table").get("0").update(function(doc) {
  return doc.merge({shareRecords: doc("shareRecords").add(
     r.expr([{"update_Id":"update002"},{"update_Id":"update004"}]).filter(
        function(newRecord) {
           return doc("shareRecords").contains(
              function(record) {
                  return record("update_Id").eq(newRecord("update_Id"))
            }).not()
     })
   )}
)})
```

Answer (score 0):

This insert a new record if it's not previously in the embedded arrays. So it's slightly different than what you want

```
 var newShareRecords = [
     {"sharer_Id": "user001","update_Id": "update002"}
     {"sharer_Id": "user001","update_Id": "update004"}
 ]

 r.table("data").merge(function(doc) {
     return {
         shareRecords: doc("shareRecords").setIntersection(newShareRecords)
     }
 })
```

If you really want to check only `update_id` you can do

```
 r.table("data").merge(function(doc) {
     return {
         shareRecords: doc("shareRecords").add(
             r.expr(newShareRecords).filter( function(newRecord) {
                 return doc("shareRecords").contains(function(record) {
                     return record("update_id").eq(newRecord("update_id")
                 }) 
             }) 
         )
     }
 })
```